# Login with GET API in VBA

Tags: vba

Here is what I have tried. This connects to the front page of the website, but I am unable to figure out how to get it to login.

```
Sub SendAPIrequest()

    Dim HTTPreq As Object, url As String, response As String, object As String

    Set HTTPreq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    object = ""

    url = "my url" & object

    With HTTPreq
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
    End With

    response = HTTPreq.responseText
    Debug.Print response 

End Sub
```

Comment: This would be entirely dependent on how the website or API is set up to log a user in. In other words, we also don't know.

Comment: Gotcha.  Is there a generic way to figure that out?

Comment: No. It would either be captured in documentation that the owner of that site or API endpoint provides, or it would take some forensics on their site (analyzing their HTML and javascript and whatnot). If you are using Chrome, you can click `F12` and there is a wealth of exploration tools to expose the DOM, javascript, css, a js console, etc. Other browsers have a similar toolset. Definitely takes a bit of expertise and often times reverse engineering and trial-and-error.